# Copias $.class en archivos jar

Tags: java, maven, compilar, jar

Cuando compilo con maven genero un jar, pero cuando lo descomprimo, me genera archivos copias de varios archivos con el simbolo `$.class`, ¿cómo puedo omitir este tipo de copias?

Ejemplo:

```
dao.class
dao$1.class
```

Comment: ¿Para qué quieres omitirlos? ¿Sabes qué representan esas clases?

Comment: Por que son copias de clases que ya se encuentran en el programa, estoy generando una migración ANT a MAVEN. Esto me genera clases que no necesito.

Comment: Eso no tiene que ver con maven, no son las mismas clases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagina que tienes una clase como

```
class A { ...}
```

Que guardas en `A.java`. Esto genera al compilar un fichero `A.class`.

Ahora imagina que tienes además una interfaz (o clase) así:

```
interface B {
   public void hola();
}
```

Que guardas en `B.java`. Esto genera al compilar un fichero `B.class`.

Y, para completar este ejemplo,imagina que en tu clase `A` necesitas un objeto que cumpla `B`, así que declaras una clase *anónima*:

```
class A {
    private B b= new B() {
        public void hola() { };
    };
}
```

Tu atributo B es una clase que cumple la interfaz B, pero no es una clase B, sino una clase *anónima* (sin nombre), así que el compilador la guarda en `A$1.class`, porque es una clase creada dentro de A.

Si borras ese archivo, **tu programa dejará de funcionar** y lanzará una `ClassNotFoundException`.